# Can you nest Bootstrap containers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

From the docs at http://getbootstrap.com/css/

> You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note
>   that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

and

> Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing
>   your outermost .container to .container-fluid.

The second sentence seems to imply that you can have nested containers. The first sentence seems to imply that there should be a single container one a page.

Which is it?

(A case might be wanting to nest a container-fluid inside a container - or simply inside some other element with a fixed width).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on the ability to use container-fluid

```css
h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.container {
  border: solid 5px red;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nested-container {
  border: solid 3px green;
}
.container-fluid {
  border: solid 3px blue;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
hr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container nested-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-md-4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Interesting example.  But when the window is resized to width >=768px, the green nested-container starts exceeding the boundaries of the outer red container.